# How to change machine name on Tfs administration Console

Tags: tfs

I need to change default machine name on TFS adminitration Console.

i find some `tfsconfig.exe` parameter below. But i couldn't change TFS 2010 configuration.

```
tfsconfig prepSql /sqlInstance:<ServerName>
```

where ServerName is the name of the new sql instance. Repeat this command for all new sql instances in your deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change web.config `applicationDatabase` key to change **computer_name**.
The file path is : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config

```
<add key="applicationDatabase" value="Data Source=**computer_name**;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STEP 1: Verify the Data Tier Summary in TFS Administration console is right

STEP 2: If the computer name(server name) is wrong then update 
the "application database" key in 
ProgramFiles -> Microsoft TFS 11.0 -> Application Tier -> 
Web Services -> web.config with the correct computer name
```